# Software watchdog causing system reboot if started at bootup

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, watchdog

In my device I enabled software [watchdog](https://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog) to monitor a file which is updated every 5 second by a application. I have [configured](https://linux.die.net/man/5/watchdog.conf) software watchdog as below

```
file = /data/file_name_to_watch
change = 10
```

Watchdog is getting started at bootup using below command **during bootup**:

```
/usr/sbin/watchdog.sh -f -v -c watchdog.conf
```

**Application which is responsible to update the file(file_name_to_watch) is started after watchdog deamon during bootup**. File being monitored by watchdog is updated every 5 seconds by the application.

**Problem is** that watchdog is rebooting the system if it is started at bootup and this same problem doesn't exist when watchdog is not started at bootup but started manually after application is launched.

```
dmesg shows "Watchdog did not stop"
```

Also, changing the watchdog configuration file to below didn't help.

```
  file = /data/file_name_to_watch
  change = 20
```

I have checked that the file is getting updated before 10 seconds elapsed after watchdog is launched during bootup.

Any pointers to debug this problem will be appreciated.

Code which I am using for watchdog: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/122/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugged and found the problem to be time(NULL) returning a huge number in src/file_stat.c

This was happening due to date being not set very early during bootup.